# WPF TabControl.Resources - Style one tab only

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I am defining a TabControl as follows:

```
<TabControl Name="TabsControl"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTabViewModel}">

    <TabControl.Resources>

        <!-- Rate Tables Tab -->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:RateTablesViewModel}">
            <v:RateTablesUserControl />
        </DataTemplate>

        <!-- Rate Tables Tab -->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:RulesViewModel}">
            <v:RulesUserControl />

        </DataTemplate>

        <!-- Rate Tables Tab -->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CreateEmployeeMatchViewModel}">
            <v:CreateEmployeeMatchUserControl />
        </DataTemplate>

        <!-- Rate Tables Tab -->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ReportViewModel}">
            <v:ReportUserControl />
        </DataTemplate>

        <!-- System Setup Tab -->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SystemSetupViewModel}">
            <v:SystemSetupUserControl />
        </DataTemplate>

    </TabControl.Resources>


    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}" />
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>

</TabControl>
```

In my Dictionary I have the following style:

```
<!-- Style for showing/hiding Setup tab -->
<Style x:Key="SetupTabStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                               AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.StartArg}" Value="Setup">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                               AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.StartArg}" Value="Edit">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

How do I apply this style to just the SystemSetup tab?

Comment: What's wrong with `relevantTabItem.Style = Resources["SetupTabStyle"] as Style;`?

Comment: @sheridan Where would I put this at?  I don't have a point in my code that defines the 'relevantTabItem' as these are all setup as DataTemplates. I thought there woudl be a way to add it within the specific <DataTemplate> tag or in the <v:SystemSetupUserControl> tag.